# Laravel 5.4 not showing Stack Trace

Tags: centos, laravel-5.4

I Deployed the code to live server. Its CentOs using vhosts.
I am having difficulties debugging. It does not shows laravel error with stack trace. It takes directly to apache 500 error page.
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3q2S.png)

Although, it logs the error in `storage/logs/laravel.log`. It is really cumbersome to debug through laravel.log file.

PS. There are some other sites ruuning on vshosts which I don't want to get messed up if I change server setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's work as it should. Stack trace on production is not a good idea. But, if you really need it go to `.env` file and set:

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```